# MongoDB 2.6.5 create admin role

Tags: mongodb, admin, privileges

On **MongoDB 2.6.5**, I'm trying to create an `Admin` user on my `Admin DB`, by running this code:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "MY_ADMIN_USER",
        pwd: "SOME_STROG_PASSWORD",
        roles: [ {
                    role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                    db: "admin"
                } ]
    }
);
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
 Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on admin to 
    execute command
     {
     createUser: "MY_ADMIN_USER",
     pwd:   "xxx",
     roles: [{
                role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                db:     "admin"
              }],
     digestPassword: false,
     writeConcern: { 
                    w:"majority",
                    wtimeout: 30000.0
                    }
     }
```

When logging in to my app's DB I have all the privileges.

But on the admin db it looks like I have none.

**Thanks for answering.**

Comment: What credentials are you using to run db.CreateUser ? It seems this user doesn't have read/write permissions on the Admin database. What happens if you try to grant these to that user ?

Comment: Well, if it's OS credentials that u'r talking about - then it's `root`. about the mongo db credentials, I just logged in with `mongo` and no authentication.

Answer (score 2):

OK! so I found the problem.

If you ever run into something like that you can baypass it with `root` credentials.

When using root user, run `vi /etc/mongod.conf` to enter the config file.

chnage the value of `auth` to false. now be careful, becouse this could be a major security issue.

I suggest you close the relevant port while doing this thing..

Restart mongo service to apply the change:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Login to your mongodb admin DB and then run the command for creating the user.

```
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "MY_ADMIN_USER",
        pwd: "SOME_STROG_PASSWORD",
        roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
    }
);
```

So now you can..

**Log out,
change the auth parameter back to true, and restart mongo service (and open the port that I foced you to close lol).**